# Finding and deleting Xcode beta marker

Tags: xcode

I have a new version of an app to submit and accidentally opened it with Xcode 11 (latest beta); now Apple reject a binary built with non-beta Xcode 10 (the message warning that builds can only be submitted from non-beta Xcode).
I'm guessing that somewhere in my project is a marker identifying the build erroneously as from Xcode 11.
I'm hoping someone can let me know how to remove this pointer so I can submit my app.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Make sure all of your projects (including pods) is compatible with one stable Xcode.

[image: Example]

2 - In organizer window

- Right click on the archive on select show in finder
- Right click on archive and select show package contents
- Head to de product -> application
- Right click on YourApp.app and select show package contents
- Open info.plist
- Change the value of `DTXcodeBuild` to `10E1001` (The version of older stable Xcode)

[image: Xcode version]

- Change the value of `BuildMachineOSBuild` to `18D42`